# How can I access the 'exerciseObject' from developer console?

Tags: javascript

How can I access the 'exerciseObject' users by the event function of the bottom from the console and interact with it?

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One worst way I would do is, add a line `debugger;` at the place where you want to have it checked.

And in the console drawer, type in the variable and get the value at that point.

---

Better way, click on the Sources, find the place you want to add a debugger and click on the line number to make it like this:

[image: preview]

In the above image, see how the Line Number: 32 has got a breakpoint set. And on the right side, you can see the local variables.

Comment: Why is `debugger;` the worst way?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Isn't it? Coz it's better to set a breakpoint right?

Comment: Depends on the situation. Console breakpoints sometimes get ignored.

Comment: Okay, not good when it's blindly deployed right? That's what I meant. 

Comment: _"not good when it's blindly deployed right?"_ - I'd agree with that.

Comment: Thanks @evolutionxbox